# Difference between "by November" and "in November"

Tags: prepositions

> "Gurman previously said the first Apple Silicon Mac would be announced
> "by" November, but today's wording narrows this down to "in" November,
> making it unlikely that we will be hearing about Apple Silicon Macs at
> next week's Apple event."

Could somebody explain to me the difference between "by November" and "in November"?

Comment: “by” means the announcement could happen at any time between now and then. It could happen “in” November, but it could also happen “in” October.

Comment: @StephenS I disagree that it could happen 'in' November, since 'by' implies that the event will already have been completed by the time November begins.

Comment: @kandyman When I tell my boss I’ll have a report to him “by Friday”, I’m probably going to deliver it “on” Friday but *may* deliver it sooner. IOW, “by” is inclusive.

Comment: Maybe it's just a difference of opinion, but I don't think 'by' is inclusive in all cases by any means. A report that is due by Friday should be delivered either before Friday or the first thing on Friday morning, unless otherwise specified. If a boss asks for a report by Friday, it is unlikely he means 'any time before 5pm on Friday', IMO. Besides,if 'by November' included any time in November, there would be no need to change the wording in the article mentioned by the OP. Also, the length of time is important. An inclusive 'By Friday' is one day - 'by November' would be 31 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`by November` is usually understood to mean an unspecified time somewhere in the period up to and until the start of November, i.e. any time before November 1st.  `by` is a bit like a deadline - something has to be completed by a certain time/date.

`in November` means during the month of November, i.e. between November 1st and November 31st.

Note that there can be disagreement (even among native speakers) about the precise meaning of 'by' in such a context, as discussed in a different stack exchange thread [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193777/meaning-of-by-when-used-with-dates-inclusive-or-exclusive). Some native speakers use ‘by’ as **inclusive**, i.e. `by November` meaning any time before or during November.

Comment: My admittedly British sense of 'by November' is that it means 'not later than 30 November', and it is supported by Cambridge Dictionaries: "**not later than; at or before**:
She had promised to be back by five o'clock.
The application must be in by the 31st to be accepted.
By the time I got to the station the train had already gone.". When it comes to hyping a product, I would expect the 'not later than' (the named month) meaning.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Fair point. It’s a little strange that the English-speaking world has never nailed down a precise definition for this. Seems like it could cause a lot of misunderstandings.

Comment: I always understood by a time to mean at or before that time, and by a period (e.g. a day, month, year), as between now and the end of that period. Precision may be achieved by specifying a time during that period. JFK said on May 25, 1961, that the US "should commit itself to achieving the goal, before this decade is out" of landing a human on the moon; this is very often summarised as 'by the end of the decade'